# dynamic Bitmap drawable in android

Tags: android, android-resources

I am wondering how i can set a Bitmap drawable resource from a dynamic variable that is the image name/ type string:

```
public CustomIcon getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String label;
        String image;
        DataBaseManager db = new DataBaseManager(context);
        label = db.getIconLabel(mIcons.get(position));
        image = db.getIconImage(mIcons.get(position));
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(parent.getResources(),
                parent.getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
        Log.v(TAG, "current pos:"+ position);
        CustomIcon icon = new CustomIcon(context, bitmap,label);

        return icon;
    }
```

**the part in question is**

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(parent.getResources(),
                         R.drawable.[image]);
```

**CODE CHANGED ABOVE** -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to deal with this is to get the resource ID first and then use the BitmapFactory method:

```
String imgName = "myicon";
int resID = parent.getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", "my.app.package.name");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(parent.getResources(), resID);
```

Comment: ah thanks i was just coming back to close this thread,..  i ended up doing it a little different than you suggested and am updating the code above.. is there a an advantage to doing it your way or mine?  see above edit -